# two for loop inside another break loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have two for loop inside another, I want to break loop if

```
$i=1 and $ii < 180
```

condition

I declared that in a if statement but it doesnt work, it prints smaller than 180 $ii values.

```
for ($i=1;$i<6;$i+=2) {

    for($ii=1;$ii<1733;$ii+=3) { 

        if( $i == 1 && $ii < 180 ){ break; }
        echo '--'.$i.'-'.$ii.'--</br>';

    }

}
```

how can fix this

Comment: Won't this just break during the first iteration?

Comment: @deceze you can try that code to see result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## New Answer

```
for ($i=1;$i<6;$i+=2) {
    for($ii=1;$ii<1733;$ii+=3) { 
        if( $i == 1 && $ii < 180 ){ continue; }
        echo '--'.$i.'-'.$ii.'--</br>';
    }
}
```

## Old Answer

You need to use:

```
break 2;
```

as you are breaking 2 loops.

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: I didn't even know this existed, always used a bool to break the parent for, thanks for sharing!

Comment: when i use break 2 it prints nothing

Comment: yes i turned all error reporting with ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @WishtobeNothing $i == 1 && $ii < 180 is true for the first loop. So it breaks before you print.

Comment: as i know if there is nested loop, nested completes all for each parent loop

Comment: shortly i want to break loop until $i = 1 and $ii < 180 how to do?

Comment: @WishtobeNothing Sorry I do not understand. You enter loop 1, than enter loop 2, than enter the if statement (as it is true), than leave both loops.

Comment: yes it should break until 180 and it should print from 180+ but it prints nothing

Comment: @WishtobeNothing Maybe you do not want to `break 2;`, you want to `continue;`?

Comment: loop also continue itself, break breaks current loop cycle (as i know ), OR is it broke whole current loop up to 1733 ?

Comment: @WishtobeNothing Please try to replace your if statement with `if( $i == 1 || $ii < 180 ){ continue; }`. Break will avoid getting values you seem to want to print.

Comment: but this will returns true when $i=2 and others. I just want to start from $i=1 and $ii>180

Comment: @WishtobeNothing So you want `$i == 1 && $ii > 180` and not `$i == 1 && $ii < 180` as stated before? Why shouldn't this work? Can you give an example of what you want and what you do not want?

Comment: i have html table has links in three column to be scrapped ,second loop is column rows, has 1730 total. I added first 180 rows of column 1 to my database and dont want to add again for each script run so it tooks 60 hours total i divided to days script run

Comment: @WishtobeNothing According to this `if ($i == 1 && $ii < 180) { continue; }` is right.

Comment: @WishtobeNothing have you tried? What output is wrong? What do you get?

Comment: It Works. Sorry about previous comment, i thought continue is same as loop resume. So I tested it if( $i == 1 && $ii < 180 ){ continue; } it works fine. thanks a lot!